# Matsumura Commutative Ring Theory Thm 16.6 Explanation for "obvious" implications?

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, modules, homological-algebra

The proof of the following theorem from Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory features the claim that obviously $(1) \implies (2) \implies (2')$.
Unfortunately while $(1) \implies (2')$ is obvious, I fail to see how $(2) \implies (2')$ is. Any help would be appreciated.

**Theorem 16.6.** Let A be a Noetherian ring, M a finite A-module and I
an ideal of A; suppose that IM $\neq$ M. For a given integer $n > 0$ the following
conditions are equivalent;
(1)  $Ext^{i}$(N, M) = 0  for all $i<n$ and for any finite A-module N with
Supp(N) $\subset$ V(I);
(2)  $Ext^{i}$(A/I, M) = 0  for all $i < n$;
(2') $Ext^{i}_{A}$(N, M) = 0 for all $i < n$ and for some finite A-module N with
Supp(N) = V(I);
(3) there exists an M-sequence of length n contained in I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather clear since $A/I$ is a finite $A$-module with $\mathrm{supp}(A/I) = V(I)$.

Maybe you were confused (as I was for a moment) that (2') does not state the condition for *all* finite modules with the property. Just one is sufficient.